# styleClass genérico na tabela

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

estou montando uma tabela e queria saber o seguinte: Quero colocar um estilo css nos cabeçalhos das colunas, é preciso usar um styleClass em cada cabeçalho ou consigo declarar um genérico pra todos os cabeçalhos?

```
<p:dataTable styleClass="tabela">
               <p:column headerText="HP" >                            
               </p:column>
               <p:column headerText="Atk">                             
               </p:column>
               <p:column headerText="Def">                             
               </p:column>
               <p:column headerText="S.Atk">                             
               </p:column>
               <p:column headerText="S.Def">                             
               </p:column>
               <p:column headerText="Spd">                             
               </p:column>
               </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se o "cabeçalho" for uma `<th>` você pode colocar no seu estilo assim:

```
table th { ... }
```